# How to save the state of UISegmentedControl in Swift3 with userDefaults

Tags: ios, swift3, nsuserdefaults, xcode8, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl called langSeg with two indexes labeled [English & German] , which controls the language of labels in my app using the code below:

```
@IBAction func indexChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    switch langSeg.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0:

        let language = "en"
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: language, ofType: "lproj")
        let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)
        headerLbl.text = bundle?.localizedString(forKey: "HLbl", value: nil, table: nil)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(["en"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")

    case 1:

        let language = "de"
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: language, ofType: "lproj")
        let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)
        descLbl.text = bundle?.localizedString(forKey: "DLbl", value: nil, table: nil)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(["de"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

to switch between English and German languages and save the user's selection; this code is working fine, but when I relaunch my App after changing the language to German for example, the labels titles are saved in German language but the segmentedControl state changed back to the English title [index 0].
Please, I need help to save the user's selection of the UISegmentedControl, any help is really appreciated.
I tried this code:

```
langSeg.selectedSegmentIndex = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "SegmentIndex")
```

inside

```
@IBAction func indexChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl)
```

After the switch brackets, but unfortunately it didn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    @IBAction func segmentSelected(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.selectedSegmentIndex, forKey: "chosenLanguage")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let value = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "chosenLanguage"){
            let selectedIndex = value as! Int
            segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = selectedIndex
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the segmented control.

```
index = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "SegmentIndex")
segmented.selectedSegmentIndex = index
```

I would put this inside your viewWillAppear method or something similar. Just make sure it is after you initialize your segmented control.

Comment: Where can I add this code? I tried it inside the @IBAction, but the segmentedControl became not switchable.

Comment: I would add it in `viewDidAppear`